# how do I create an enum from a string representation? c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, enums

im trying to pass back from a user control a list of strings that are part of an enum, like this:

```
<bni:products id="bnProducts" runat="server" ProductsList="First, Second, Third"  />
```

and in the code behid do something like this:

```
public enum MS 
    {
        First = 1,
        Second,
        Third
    };
    private MS[] _ProductList;
    public MS[] ProductsList
    {
        get
        {
            return _ProductList;
        }
        set
        {
            _ProductList = how_to_turn_string_to_enum_list;
        }
    }
```

my problem is I dont know how to turn that string into a list of enum, so what should be "how_to_turn_string_to_enum_list"? or do you know of a better way to use enums in user controls? I really want to be able to pass a list that neat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Enum.Parse` is the canonical way to parse a string to get an enum:

```
MS ms = (MS) Enum.Parse(typeof(MS), "First");
```

but you'll need to do the string splitting yourself.

However, your property is currently of type `MS[]` - the `value` variable in the setter won't be a string. I suspect you'll need to make your property a string, and parse it there, storing the results in a `MS[]`. For example:

```
private MS[] products;

public string ProductsList
{
    get
    {
        return string.Join(", ", Array.ConvertAll(products, x => x.ToString()));
    }
    set
    {
        string[] names = value.Split(',');
        products = names.Select(name => (MS) Enum.Parse(typeof(MS), name.Trim()))
                        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

I don't know whether you'll need to expose the array itself directly - that depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 6):

This is a *short* solution, but it doesn't cover some very important things like localization and invalid inputs.

```
private static MS[] ConvertStringToEnumArray(string text)
{
    string[] values = text.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    return Array.ConvertAll(values, value => (MS)Enum.Parse(typeof(MS), value));
}
```

Comment: +1 for validation. From the example, localization isn't much of an issue because this isn't user-supplied data - it's in the page code.

Answer (score 4):

You need to look at the [System.Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559(loband).aspx) method.

Comment: this one "or"s the values passed, not what im looking for

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Of course this method just converts one single value to an Enum, you need to loop through all and apply the method on each element ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] stringValues = inputValue.Split(',');

_ProductList = new MS[stringValues.Length];

for (int i=0;i< stringValues.Length;i++)
  _ProductList[i] = (MS) Enum.Parse(typeof(MS), stringValues[i].Trim());
```

(updated my code because I misread your code)

Answer (score 0):

Mark your enum with the [Flags] attribute, and combine flags instead of an array of enum values.

Comment: That's not always valid. For instance, HTTP response codes aren't *logically* flags - but you might have a collection of them (e.g. "I handle these response codes"). Don't rush to use flags for enums which aren't logically flags.